# Android Circular Side Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to build an circular side bar floating button menu which will look like a wheel rotating 360 degree with menu items around it and should be able to swipe and set click listener.i have check the circular floating button library and it doesn't rotate on swiped.so how could i implement this??[image: no exactly like this..but this is the reference image]

Comment: There's nothing built in, so you'll have to do it 100 percent custom.  Which makes it probably too broad of a question.  I'd start by figuring out how to layout the view for a static ring, get that working, then add in rotation.

Comment: [Gabe Sechan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1631193/gabe-sechan) right: You need custom view for this. Take a look at [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) and tutorials like [that](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html)